# Router won't allow Port forward from 192.168.X.X

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I'm trying to set up a port forward on my home network for a small game server and have encountered a problem with assigning the forward to a local IP.

**The Problem:**
[image: The Problem]

My machine's local IP is `192.186.1.11`.
It doesn't allow me to change the 3rd set of numbers.

In the hope to get around this, I attempted to change the local IP on the machine with:

```
sudo ifconfig enp3s0 192.168.0.98 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

As it did change the IP, it prevented me from reconnecting to the router.
The router is an *Ubee DVW3201B* and I am running on Ubuntu.

What can I do to somehow bypass this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That picture doesn't show much, but it seems your router thinks your local network is 192.168.0.0/24. What are the IP addresses of your other hosts and your router (internal, not WAN)?

If they are all on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, maybe your router interface is just badly programmed and the port forwarding will actually work for 192.168.1.X instead of 192.168.0.X as it says.

If that doesn't work, maybe you could change the local network (if it's a small, simple network) to be 192.168.0.0/24 instead of 192.168.1.0/24 - I once had an old router that I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to properly configure to use a different address than the default.

Comment: As it turns out, I was literally connecting to the wrong router via ethernet.. so It gave my machine an address from the other router. Just wish I would have caught that before writing a question lol. Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Never really understood the ones that accept the answer without _upvoting_ `:-)`.